# selecting first article inside of a section

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have this html:

```
<section id=mainContent">

    <h2>Lorremis</h2>

    <article class="one"></article>
    <article class="two"></article>
    <article class="three"></article>
    <article class="four"></article>
    <article class="five"></article>
    <article class="six"></article>
    <article class="seven"></article>
    <article class="eight"></article>
    <article class="nine"></article>

</section>
```

Each article has an image and a couple of paragraphs inside them.

If i apply the following css code:

```
section#mainContent article:nth-child(2) {

    display: none;

}
```

I expect the second article to display none. This does not happen though. The first article dissapears instead of the second. Now, if i remove the h2 tag, the first article dissapears as it should.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have said, `nth-child` selects child independent of tag type. You can use the `nth-of-type` selector instead

```
#mainContent article:nth-of-type(2) { display none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `nth-child` is looking at all the children of #mainContent, not just the article elements. As defined, `:nth-child()` matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, so it's being compared to all its siblings, including the `<h2>`. You're probably looking for `:nth-of-type`.

Answer (score 1):

`article:nth-child(2)` literally means "choose an article element, which is the second child of its parent".

In your example the first child is always `h2`.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you need compatibility old browser you may use this selector

```
#maincontent article:first-child + article {}
```